# How to select a group header in WPF-ListBox?

Tags: wpf, listbox, grouping

I am using a ListBox to group the items...When I use my key board to move down/up in the list of items in listbox...the header of any griuping is not getting selected.

Header is having a dotted border...but it is NOT selected...the style for a selected item is not applied to it...also when I hit enter (when header has a dotted border) it select the last selected item(which is non-header item)...

any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT:**

If the listbox has following data (where "hand" and "leg" as header)...If I use my keyboard to move down..through the items, I can see that a dotted border when I reach the header(hand or leg)...But it is not selected.

**Hand**
       Fingers
       Nails
**Leg**
       Fingers
       Nails

Comment: A group header is precisely that.... a Group Header... it's not a selectable item in the ListBox... I don't know what you mean, but you got it wrong.

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to select it?

Comment: That is the requirement from my client :(..I know it is kind of wierd.

Comment: what do you expect to happen when its selected? just highlight like the list items?